# how to return null values from a set of data to show in SQL

Tags: sql-server, null

So if I'm giving a set of data, and a small part of data are not being inserted into the database, how do I show them as actual "records" in SQL server?

```
select *
from cleansedcarddatabase 
where clientcreditcards in (
'1235980878',
'1235980918',
'1235980969',
'1235980971',
'1235981010',
'1235981014',
'1235981033',
'1235981777',
'1235981321',
'1235981944',
'1235981200'
)
```

Some of the credit cards clients decided to cancel at last moment, but so those two records never got inserted into database. But I do still want to show those null value cards(since there's no data) from the list of cards(most are inserted). Is there way to do this without temp table?

Let's say I forgot which two card numbers are the ones that didn't got inserted into database, instead just show nothing or the 9 record, anyway to display those two null records as "real" data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a column with a card number stored in your database table `cleansedcarddatabase` called `CardNumber`, you could reformat your list of card numbers in to a list of values, and then join to your database table on the card number, then display all columns from your database table (because your OP is just using `select *` from the database table):

```
select 
    db_credit_cards.* 
from    
    (values ('1235980878'),
            ('1235980918'),
            ('1235980969'),
            ('1235980971'),
            ('1235981010'),
            ('1235981014'),
            ('1235981033'),
            ('1235981777'),
            ('1235981321'),
            ('1235981944'),
            ('1235981200')) AS all_credit_cards(CardNumber)
    left join cleansedcarddatabase as db_credit_cards ON all_credit_cards.CardNumber = db_credit_cards.CardNumber;
```

This would allow any records in `cleansedcarddatabase` to display the data that has been stored there, and then display nulls for the card numbers in your list of values that do not exist in the database table.

If you provide more information regarding the schema `cleansedcarddatabase` and your actual desired output columns, I can edit this ansewer with a more specific example using this technique.